The rank of Sylow subgroup of special linear groups over finite fields
Let $p,\ell$ be two primes, and let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a finite field of order $q=p^r$. We define the rank of a finite group $G$ to the smallest cardinality of a generating set for $G$. We denote by $\operatorname{rk}_{\ell}({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{q}))$ the rank of Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{q})$. My question is the following:

Let $n\geq 2$. What is $\operatorname{rk}_{\ell}({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{q}))$ precisely?

For $n=2$ and $q=p$, I know that $\operatorname{rk}_{\ell}({\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{p}))=1$ for all $\ell\neq 2$ because every Sylow $\ell$-subgroup is cyclic in this case. Any references would be highly appreciated.

Your claim that every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\mbox{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic can't possibly be true. There's a theorem of Burnside, Holder, and Zassenhaus stating that when a group has exclusively cyclic Sylow subgroups, then the group in question is solvable. However, if $p$ is at least 5, then $\mbox{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has a nonabelian composition factor found by factoring out by the center.

@Chris I am not claiming Sylow $2$-subgroup of ${\rm SL}2(\mathbb{F}{p})$ is cyclic. In fact, ${\rm SL}2(\mathbb{F}{p})$ has periodic cohomology, i.e. every Sylow $\ell$-subgroup is cyclic or generalized quaternion group (only occur if $\ell=2$).

If $G$ is a $p$-group (more generally, a nilpotent group), then a subset $X$ generates $G$ if and only if the image of $X$ in $G^{\rm ab}$ generates $G^{\rm ab}$.

Are you allowing the case $\ell=p$? If you are things get wonky, otherwise it's fairly uniform.

@DavidA.Craven I'm interested in the case $\ell \neq p$.

The Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $SL_n(q)$ is fairly easy to write down, when $\ell\neq 2$ and $\ell\nmid (q-1)$. (The reason for this latter distinction is that the Sylow $\ell$-subgroups of $GL_n(q)$ and $SL_n(q)$ are the same, so we can just work with $GL_n(q)$ instead.)
Let $d$ denote the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $\ell$, i.e., the smallest $d$ such that $\ell\mid (q^d-1)$. This is clearly an important integer, given the order of $SL_n(q)$.
Let $m=\lfloor n/d\rfloor$. Notice that if $m=0$ then $\ell\nmid |GL_n(q)|$, so we can ignore that case. Write down the $\ell$-adic expansion of $m$, so $m=a_0+a_1\ell+\cdots+a_r\ell^r$ with $0\leq a_i<\ell$. The Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $SL_n(q)$ and $GL_n(q)$ is a direct product of iterated wreath products, one for each $a_i$ that is positive. It's easiest to just give a few examples than write down a general pattern, as from two or three examples it's obvious what to do.
If $m=\ell^r$ for some $r$, then the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $SL_n(q)$ has shape $C_{\ell^a}\wr C_\ell\wr C_\ell\wr \cdots \wr C_\ell$, where the number of wreathings is $r-1$. So $m=\ell^3$ yields $C_{\ell^a}\wr C_\ell \wr C_\ell$. The prime power $\ell^a$ is the exact power of $\ell$ dividing $q^d-1$. For example, if $\ell=3$, $q=8$, so $d=2$, then $a=2$ as $9$ divides $q^2-1$. Thus the Sylow $3$-subgroup of $SL_{18}(8)$ is $C_9\wr C_3\wr C_3$.
If $m=\ell^3+\ell^2$, for example, we take the direct product $SL_{d\ell^3}(q)\times SL_{d\ell^2}(q)\leq SL_n(q)$ and place the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup inside that. For $m=2\ell^2$, we take $SL_{d\ell^2}(q)\times SL_{d\ell^2}(q)\leq SL_n(q)$ and place the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup inside that.
Thus the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of an arbitrary $SL_n(q)$ is as follows: calculate $\ell^a$ based on $q$, $\ell$ and $d$. Write down the $\ell$-adic expansion of $m=\lfloor n/d\rfloor$, $a_0+a_1\ell+\cdots$. Then there are exactly $a_i$ copies of the iterated wreath product of $C_{\ell^a}$ with $C_\ell$ exactly $i$ times (so if $a_0=4$ then we just have a contribution of $C_{\ell^a}^{\times 4}$ from that term in the expansion).

Now that we have the exact structure of the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup, we have to calculate the abelianization of it. Each layer of wreath adds a new cyclic factor to the abelian quotient. So for $d\ell^3$ we have three layers to the wreath product, so rank $3$.
Thus the number of generators (which is what you are asking for, not the rank) of the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $SL_n(q)$ is, with the $\ell$-adic expansion above, $\sum_{i=1}^r (i+1)\cdot a_i$.

So what about $d=1$? Here the argument above gives the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $GL_n(q)$, and the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup of $SL_n(q)$ is a normal subgroup of this, whose quotient is $C_{\ell^a}$. The number of generators cannot decrease by more than $1$ for obvious reasons. At the time of writing I cannot remember whether it does go down by $1$ or not. It certainly does if $n<\ell$, so the Sylow $\ell$-subgroup is abelian.
I tested $SL_3(4)$ versus $GL_3(4)$ and both Sylows are $2$-generator, and both Sylows of $SL_9(4)$ and $GL_9(4)$ are $3$-generator. What I think happens is that the number of generators of the Sylow $\ell$-subgroups of $SL_{\ell^r}(q)$ and $GL_{\ell^r}(q)$ are the same, and you subtract one for any other $n$.

Does your formula still hold true when $\ell$ divides $q-1$?

@stupidboy I've realized I'm not quite right. The structure is the same, but you don't want the d-adic expansion but the $\ell$-adic expansion of $\lfloor n/d\rfloor$. I need to fix that first, then deal with the case $d=1$.

@stupidboy I have now corrected the description, and written down what I think happens in the $d=1$ case, but I cannot guarantee it.
